# Add products thumbnail to Woocommerce admin orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I would like to add futured image on admin view order pages in Woocommerce. 
New Column created, but the product image does not appear.
What should I do to show the order thumbnail?
Thanks.

```
// Admin Order page new colums
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_account_orders_column', 10, 1 );
function add_account_orders_column( $columns ){
    $columns['custom-column'] = __( 'New Column', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom-column', 'add_account_orders_column_rows' );
function add_account_orders_column_rows( $order ) {
    // Example with a custom field
    if ( $value = $order->get_meta( 'order_received_item_thumbnail_image' ) ) {
        echo esc_html( $value );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beware, as orders can have many products (many order items) and in this cas you will have many images *(also it will weigh down the page)*…

Now Your 2nd function hook is wrong and will not do anything.

To so you need to loop through order items as follow:

```
// Add a new custom column to admin order list
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'admin_orders_list_add_column', 10, 1 );
function admin_orders_list_add_column( $columns ){
    $columns['custom_column'] = __( 'New Column', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}

// The data of the new custom column in admin order list
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'admin_orders_list_column_content', 10, 2 );
function admin_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ){
    global $the_order;

    if( 'custom_column' === $column ){
        $count = 0;

        // Loop through order items
        foreach( $the_order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product(); // The WC_Product Object
            $style   = $count > 0 ? ' style="padding-left:6px;"' : '';

            // Display product thumbnail
            printf( '<span%s>%s</span>', $style, $product->get_image( array( 50, 50 ) ) );

            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: You have made me very happy, Thank you very very much

Comment: How to make this extend the wc-api so we can get the image to show in orders page on mobile apps? thanks!