# How to display items thumbnail of the order in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I would like to display the thumbnails of all items in the orders I received from my customers. I'm using [Add products thumbnail to Woocommerce admin orders list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56101563/11987538) answer code but sometimes I got error with the notice:

> "Error message: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
> get_image_id() on bool in".

I wonder how can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you are using existing code, please cite the source, because it gives proper credit to the author. Also nowhere in the code `get_image_id()` is used

Answer (score 0):

I am checking as you share the link, It's working fine but if you got an issue should be a versioning issue or something missing.

I have few/small changes, I hope this is helpful for you.

```
// Add a new custom column name "Product Image" to admin order list
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'woo_admin_orders_list_add_column', 10, 1 );

function woo_admin_orders_list_add_column( $columns ){
    $columns['custom_column'] = __( 'Product Image', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}

// The data of the new custom column value in admin order list
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'woo_add_product_image_order_column', 10, 2 );

function woo_add_product_image_order_column( $column, $post_id ){
    global $order;

    if( 'custom_column' === $column ){
        $count = 0;

        $order = wc_get_order($post_id);
        // Loop through order items
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $product = $item->get_product(); // The WC_Product Object
            $style   = $count > 0 ? ' style="padding-left:6px;"' : '';

            // Display product thumbnail
            printf( '<span%s>%s</span>', $style, $product->get_image( array( 50, 50 ) ) );

            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Rajeev, Thank you so much for your answer. Surely, this code worked very well when I did not have many orders in your system. When I got more than 500 orders, it became an error. I usually get the notification from WordPress below. I have tried to change the code as you suggested but the outcome is the same.